# sim-coder uber app : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid geo location

Tags: android

I followed sim-coder uber app and got the app in his GitHub but when I try to log in as a customer the app crash

```
10-09 12:04:27.809 17199-17199/com.simcoder.uber E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.simcoder.uber, PID: 17199
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid geo location: 120.8281794, 14.8458765
        at com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation.<init>(GeoLocation.java:51)
        at com.simcoder.uber.CustomerMapActivity.getDriversAround(CustomerMapActivity.java:540)
        at com.simcoder.uber.CustomerMapActivity.access$2300(CustomerMapActivity.java:74)
        at com.simcoder.uber.CustomerMapActivity$10.onLocationResult(CustomerMapActivity.java:483)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcec.zzt(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzcl.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzcm.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737)
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid geo location: 120.8281794, 14.8458765
>           at com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation.(GeoLocation.java:51)

You must be passing `120.8281794` as latitude which is an invalid value .

Latitude maximum range is -90 to +90 .

Please pass the correct latitude value to solve the error

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Android Studio's Emulator, make sure to change the location of the Emulator  to a location that is between -90 & 90 on Latitude, and -180 & 180 on longitude. then run your app .
I hope that might help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Android system automatically thinks that the longitude is the latitude and the latitude is the longitude.
To fix it, try this:

```
GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), 999999999);
```